# Should languages with indentation based syntax be exempted from "simple typographical error" closure?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, typographical-error

Python, for example, uses tabs or spaces to define code blocks. So beginners could legitimately be facing such a situation and not realizing it. An example would be my own [in Python 2.7.5, why is "if (code)" valid syntax but "elif (same code)" isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794109/in-python-2-7-5-why-is-if-code-valid-syntax-but-elif-same-code-isnt) question from July, 2014.

In the example question my error was that all the ELIF's **SHOULD HAVE BEEN** IF's. I was confused by the meta-knowledge that each case was mutually-exclusive to the others.

Comment: Python is indented like Guido wanted. Why is such indentation error different from me forgetting an **`{`**?

Comment: How is that different than languages where indent don't change anything but any typo might still cause an error, and something that a new coder wouldn't realize?

Comment: Because depending on the editor indentation may be hard to spot and/or search for where a missing character is easier to spot or search for.

Comment: What exactly is the feature you propose? It reads more like a discussion how the community should use their close votes.

Comment: I wasn't sure what tag to use, I guessed because the editor required one. I was going to use BOTH before I read that discussion was meant for when no other tag applied.

Comment: a typo is a typo. If the user makes a syntax error intentionally, not knowing it was a syntax error, it isn't a typo.

Comment: @Kevin B So you are saying my old question should not have been closed as I was unaware it was an indentation "typo" and though is was if versus elif syntax differences?

Comment: well, was it a typo? did you intentionally not tab it properly, because you didn't know it needed to be tabbed properly? (clearly this is all subjective, hence the voting system)

Comment: @BryanDunphy but for a newbie, ANY typo is hard to catch.... Why is python special?

Comment: Because tabs and spaces are INVISIBLE in most editors and sometimes (most GUIs) impossible to enter in "Find" boxes as well so general advice to "check (or search for) matching/equal characters" is almost impossible then.

Comment: @Kevin B - As the subject states, I thought it was a difference between IF and ELIF syntax, not a typo.

Comment: Right. in your case, i see this as a syntax error, not a typo. I wasn't arguing that the close reason chosen was correct.

Comment: Some users use editors that do not make the difference between 0 and O (digit zero and capital letter O) clear. Or 1 and l (digit one and lowercase letter L). That doesn't make a question about a typo caused by such differences any less off-topic. If a beginner makes an indentation error because they don't yet know the difference between tabs and spaces for indentation or how to visualise or correct that difference, than asking a question that is based on such errors is no less off topic for being a typo.

Comment: @BryanDunphy: Sublime text: select the text, tabs are displayed as lines, spaces as dots. Other text editors have similar features. There are also numerous variations on the 'replace tabs with spaces' operation and the 'indent using spaces' setting.

Comment: @BryanDunphy: and in *this specific case*, I see no evidence of a mixture of tabs and spaces. The [original first revision raw post contents](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49ca0767-d1e1-4b6c-912b-784d45ee0188/view-source) only uses spaces. As a prolific Python question answerer, I know where to look. So in this case, the OP simply didn't know how to indent properly, an error on par with forgetting to use curly braces.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: "*Sublime text:*" They're newbies; they're probably using Notepad. Granted, I agree that the OP is wrong on such questions; a typo is a typo even if it's spacing. But expecting that new users use an advanced text editor is not a reasonable expectation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: or not using Windows at all. In my case my computer is a Mac and I was using Xcode (Apple's OFFICIAL IDE) which has Python syntax coloring, just as it does for Objective-C and Swift.

Answer (score 8):

In the posted question, it is ambiguous whether it's a *logic error* or a *syntax error*. Perhaps the indentation was meant that way but OP didn't realise the need for `if..elif` statements to chain. Though having said that, realistically, we can all guess what was meant.

How is this different from other misplaced or missing braces?

```
if (foo)
    bar();
    baz();
```

Well, this doesn't work like most newbies expect either. Is that a logic issue, or a syntax issue?

When the code *says* one thing but the OP is clearly expecting it to behave differently than it does, and the reason for that dissonance **is incorrect syntax**… then closing it as such is warranted. The syntax of the language you're writing is the most basic skill you have to master first. If you're not aware of the importance of indentation in Python, or the use of braces in most other languages, you need to go back to the very basics of the language. These are not generally questions we want to entertain here, because there are an infinite number of ways in which you can typo syntax and each case almost never helps anyone else ever again.

The only exception to this I would say are situations with very non-obvious and subtle syntax issues. Something like the infamous `-->` operator which comes up every so often; it's useful having one canonical answer for that.

Comment: 99% of the time that is missing enclosure characters.

Comment: Auto-inserted semicolons in JavaScript is another example of "subtle syntax issues" - and we already have enough  answers for it -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745743/automatic-semicolon-insertion-return-statements.

Comment: *"Something like the infamous --> operator which comes up every so often; it's useful having one canonical answer for that."* Only because it's friendlier to close such questions as duplicates, rather than to close them as "off-topic: not a practical programming problem". So in this spirit, I agree, and would even say that if indentation problems are a common type of question that appears in Python, someone should create a canonical "What are the indentation rules in Python?" (or similar) question, and then use this as a dupe-closure target. Equivalent to closing as a typo, but friendlier.